# Загрузка файла на сервер GLPI с помощью GLPI API + Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, curl, requests

День добрый!

- Имеется Сервер - Хелпдеск система GLPI (https://glpi-project.org/). GLPI имеет API
- Имеется клиент для GLPI, написанный на Python (Python 3.4, PyQt5, PyCharm 2018.3)

Необходимо научить клиент GLPI отправлять файлы на сервер GLPI.

При использовании Shell и CURL файлы отправляются без проблем:

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-H "Session-Token: ${sessionToken}" \
-H "App-Token: ${appToken}" \
-F 'uploadManifest={"input": {"name": "Uploaded document", "_filename" : ["mail.png"]}};type=application/json' \
-F 'filename[0]=@/tmp/mail.png' "${glpiApiPath}/Document/"
```

При использовании Python при отправке возникает ошибка:

**['ERROR_UPLOAD_FILE_TOO_BIG_POST_MAX_SIZE', 'The file seems too big']**

При этом:

Настройки PHP на сервере:

```
cat /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Размер загружаемого на сервер файл: 56 KByte

Пробовал отправлять файл, используя API GLPI с помощью Python, несколькими способами, например:

```
headersPost = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                       'Session-Token': sessionToken,
                       'App-Token': appToken,
               }
 
files = {
    'uploadManifest': (None, '{"input": {"name": "Uploaded document", "_filename": ["mail.png"]}};type=application/json'),
    'filename[0]': ('mail.png', open('mail.png', 'rb')),
}
 
responseDocumentUpload = requests.post(glpiApiBaseUrl + '/Document/', headers=headersPost, files=files)
 
documentUploadJson = responseDocumentUpload.json()
print(documentUploadJson)
```

или так:

```
headersPost = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                       'Session-Token': sessionToken,
                       'App-Token': appToken,
               }

data = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'uploadManifest': '{"input": {"name": "Uploaded document", "_filename": ["mail.png"]}}',
}

files = {
    'filename[0]': ('mail.png', open('mail.png', 'rb')),
}

responseDocumentUpload = requests.post(glpiApiBaseUrl + '/Document/', headers=headersPost, files=files, data=data)

documentUploadJson = responseDocumentUpload.json()
print(documentUploadJson)
```

Результат тот же - ошибка.

Что я делаю не так? Как правильно использовать тип multipart/form-data в запросе requests для отправки файлов? CURL на SHELL используя этот тип отрабатывает ведь корректно.

Спасибо!

Comment: Подскажи как подключится к базе glpi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получилось.

```
headersPost = {
    'Session-Token': sessionToken,
    'App-Token': appToken,
}

multipart_form_data = {
    'uploadManifest': (None, '{"input": {"name": "test123.png", "_filename": ["test123.png"]}}'),
    'file': ('test123.png', open('test123.png', 'rb')),
}

# request
responseDocumentUpload = requests.post(glpiApiBaseUrl + '/Document/', headers=headersPost, files=multipart_form_data)

# get upload result
documentUploadJson = responseDocumentUpload.json()

# get file id after upload
screenshotFileId = json.dumps(documentUploadJson['id'])

# debug
print(type(screenshotFileId))
print(screenshotFileId)
```